# What conservation law corresponds to this local $U(1)$ symmetry of the CCR?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, commutator, gauge-invariance

It is known that canonical commutation relations do not fix the form of momentum operator. That means that if canonical commutation relations (CCR) are given by

$$[\hat{x}^i,\hat{p}_j]~=~i\hbar~\delta^i_j~ {\bf 1}$$

they can be satisfied by the following choice of momentum operators:

$p_x = -ih\frac{∂}{∂x}+\frac{∂f}{∂x}$

$p_y = -ih\frac{∂}{∂y}+\frac{∂f}{∂y}$

$p_z = -ih\frac{∂}{∂z}+\frac{∂f}{∂z}$

where $f(x,y,z)$ - arbitrary function.

On the other hand, for any choice of $f(x,y,z)$ momentum operators can be transformed to their most frequently used form $(-ih\frac{∂}{∂x})$ (etc for $y$ and $z$) by the following transformation of the wave function $\psi$ and operators $p$:

$\psi'=e^{-\frac{i}{h}f(x,y,z)}\psi$

$p^{'}_x =e^{-\frac{i}{h}f(x,y,z)}p_x e^{+\frac{i}{h}f(x,y,z)}=-ih\frac{∂}{∂x}$

Hence, we obtain $U(1)$ gauge transformation using only canonical commutation relations for momentum and position operators.

Does this mean that $U(1)$ gauge invariance corresponds to conservation of momentum rather than to conservation of electric charge?

Answer (score 7):

1) If we interpret OP's transformation$^1$ as a [passive transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation), i.e. a mere change of coordinates/description that doesn't alter the system, then there is no conservation law.

2) So in the following, let us interpret OP's transformation as an active transformation.

For a system to have a symmetry, its action $S$ (or more precisely, in this quantum mechanical context, its Hamiltonian operator $\hat{H}$) must respect this symmetry. The corresponding conservation law would depend on the specific form of Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$. This is all we have to say about QM.

3) Finally, in a field theoretic context, we can interpret OP's transformation

$$\tag{1} \frac{\hbar}{i} {\bf \nabla} ~\longrightarrow~  e^{-i\Lambda({\rm r})}\frac{\hbar}{i} {\bf\nabla} e^{i\Lambda({\rm r})} $$

as a pure gauge transformation in an electromagnetic theory with zero electromagnetic field strength.

When interpreted as an EM theory, on one hand, global gauge symmetry leads to electric charge conservation, cf. [Noether's first Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48305/2451) Phys.SE question.

On the other hand, there is no conserved quantity associated with local gauge symmetry per se, cf. [Noether's second Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_second_theorem). (Its off-shell Noether identity is a triviality. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26990/2451) Phys.SE question.)

--

$^1$ OP's transformation is related to the choice of phase factors in overlaps between position and momentum eigenstates in QM, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41880/2451) Phys.SE post.