# Can we correctly define momentum operator only by means of position operator and their commutation relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, definition, commutator

In "J.M. Ziman. Electrons and Phonons: The Theory of Transport Phenomena in Solids" the author  formally introduces the position (displacement) operator and then *defines* the momentum operator with the correct commutation relation $$ [\hat{u}_{l}, \hat{p}_{l'}] = i \hbar \delta_{l,l'}$$ between these two. Is such approach formally correct?

Edit: This suggestion is wrong: Can this lead to some degenerate form of "momentum operator"? First that comes to my mind is $$ \begin{aligned}\hat{p}_{l} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{l}} \quad \text{if} \quad u < u_{0} \\ \hat{p}_{l} = -i\hbar\frac{1}{u_{l}} \quad \text{if} \quad u \geq u_{0}.\end{aligned}$$ Putting this theoretical construction aside, the core of the question is that if generally such definition of an operator can be done?

Comment: Perhaps my mathematics/QM is a little rusty, but I don't believe that the latter "degenerate form" satisfies the [commutation relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation).

Comment: You might be interested in this [Physics.SE post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45067/momentum-as-generator-of-translations) and [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator#Derivation_from_infinitesimal_translations).

Answer (score 7):

(**Disclaimer**: The more rigourously inclined individual may be better suited by looking at the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem), as Qmechanic notes)

One can deduce that the momentum operator takes the form $\hat p = -\mathrm{i}\hbar\partial_x$ in the position representation from the fact that the momentum operator generates the infinitesimal translations as $T(\epsilon) = \boldsymbol{1} - \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}\epsilon \hat p $ alone:

Observe that

$$T(\epsilon)\lvert \psi \rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x \lvert x \rangle \langle x \rvert T(\epsilon)\lvert \psi \rangle \tag{1}$$

Now, $\langle x \rvert T(\epsilon) \lvert \psi \rangle= \langle x - \epsilon\vert\psi\rangle = \psi(x - \epsilon)$ . A Taylor expansion of this wavefunction yields

$$ \psi(x - \epsilon) = \psi(x) - \epsilon(\partial_x\psi)(x) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2) \tag{2}$$

Put $(2)$ into $(1)$, forget about $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ and get

$$ (\boldsymbol{1} - \frac{\mathrm{i}}{\hbar}\epsilon\hat p)\lvert \psi \rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x \psi(x) \lvert x \rangle - \int\mathrm{d}x \lvert x \rangle\epsilon \partial_x \psi(x) \implies \hat p\ = \int\mathrm{d}x \lvert x \rangle (-\mathrm{i}\hbar\partial_x)\langle x \rvert$$

Therefore, $\hat p = -\mathrm{i}\hbar\partial_x$ in the position basis. This already suggests that you have essentially no freedom in how to choose the momentum operator.

Comment: I had actually started typing something very much like this up (except I included the derivation of the form of the infinitesimal translation operator) but gave up because it was getting too long (probably because of the included derivation).

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 6):

I) Comment to the question (v1):

The Schrödinger position representation

$$\hat{p}_k 
~=~ \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial }{\partial x^k}, \qquad \hat{x}^j ~=~x^j,$$

correctly reproduces the [canonical commutation relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relations)

$$ [\hat{x}^j,\hat{p}_k ]~=~i\hbar ~\delta^j_k ~{\bf 1}, $$

while the proposal

$$\hat{p}_k 
~=~ \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{1}{x^k}, \qquad \hat{x}^j ~=~x^j,  \qquad\leftarrow \text{(Wrong!)} $$

simply commutes

$$ [\hat{x}^j,\hat{p}_k ]~=~0. $$

II) Comment to the question (v2): It seems OP is essentially asking:

> *What is the most general expression for the position representation of the momentum operator?*

This was e.g. asked in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70203/2451) Phys.SE post. See also [Stone von Neumann theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem).

Comment: You're right, was too hasty with my calculation from top of my head.