# Coefficient of an 1-form in position-representation of momentum operator where configuration space is NOT $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differential-geometry, momentum, commutator

[image]

I found this in the book Geometric Phase in Quantum Systems by A. Bohm et al.

Where the position space representation of the momentum operator carries a (Where exactly my doubt is) coefficient of 1-form with the condition

$$\partial_i \omega_j - \partial_j \omega_i =0 \implies d\omega=0$$

The author(s) argued about $Poincare \ lemma$ and how, for $\mathbb{R}^m$ configuration space the term can be $gauged \ away$.

I understand usual momentum operator representation without this 1-form, and this is very non-trivial for me.

Can someone please explain me how this comes and what it means in details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For $M=\mathbb{R}^m$, starting from the [canonical commutation relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) (CCRs), we have the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem), which proves the existence of the standard Schrödinger position representation (i.e. without the 1-form $\omega$) up to unitary equivalence, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45248/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. However conjugating with unitary multiplication operators naturally induces an exact $\omega$ one-form, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/70206/2451).
3. Therefore it is quite natural to consider a 1-form $\omega$ from the onset, even for a topologically non-trivial $m$-dimensional [configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)) $M$.
4. The CCRs then imply that the 1-from $\omega$ must be a closed one-form. The cohomology class $[\omega]$ is conserved under conjugating with unitary multiplication operators.
5. Since $M=\mathbb{R}^m$ is a [contractible space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space), we may use [Poincare Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) to show that the cohomology class $[\omega]=[0]$ is trivial.