# Noether Charge and Gauge Fields

Tags: conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

I understand the global gauge symmetry results conserved charges associated with the symmetry. My question is, why don't we have conserved charges associated with local gauge symmetry of the gauge fields $A$ itself? Why don't we have a conserved charge for the Lagrangian $\int \mathrm{Tr}\left( F\wedge\star F\right)$? Please elaborate in both abelian case and non-abelian case.

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/159444/50583).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57901/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66092/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112367/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159273/2451 , and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

The abelian case:

The Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L} = F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}
$$
is invariant off shell under local gauge symmetry
$$
A_\mu(x) \mapsto A_\mu (x) - \partial_\mu \theta(x)
$$
The Noether current is
$$
J^\mu(x) = \frac{\delta{L}}{\delta \partial^\mu A_\nu} \delta A_\nu
= F^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu \theta(x)
$$
So the Noether charge is:
$$
Q = \int d^3x. J^0 = \int d^3x. F^{0i} \partial_i \theta(x)
= - \int d^3x. (\partial_i F^{0i}) \theta(x) = 0
$$
where the last equality follows from equation of motion: $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = 0$.

Surprisingly! The Noether charge is 0!!!

It seems to violate the 'Noether charge theorem' which states that the Noether charge should be the quantum generator of the transformation:
$$
[Q_\theta, A_\mu(x)] = -\partial_\mu \theta(x)
$$
But it is reasonable, that in the proof of 'Noether charge theorem' we used the canonical commutation relation:
$$
\begin{align}
[Q,\phi(y)] &= \int d^3x. [\frac{\delta L}{\delta \partial_0 \phi} \mathcal{F}, \phi(y)]\\
&= [\int d^3x. \mathcal{P} \mathcal{F}, \phi(y)]\\
&= \int d^3x. [\mathcal{P}(x), \phi(y)] \mathcal{F}(x)\\
&= \int d^3x. \delta^{(3)}(x-y) \mathcal{F}(x)\\
&= \mathcal{F}(y)
\end{align}
$$
where the transformation is $\phi(x)\mapsto \phi(x) + \mathcal{F}(x)$ and $\mathcal{P}(x)$ is the canonical momentum. And we used canonical commutation relation $[\mathcal{P}(x), \phi(y)] = \delta^{(3)}(x-y)$. But in QED the canonical commutation relation is different: canonical momentum is $\mathcal{P}^\nu = F^{0\nu}$ and we impose(Srednicki 55.20)
$$
[F^{0\nu}, A^\sigma] = (\delta^{\nu\sigma} - \frac{\partial^\nu \partial^\sigma}{\nabla^2})\delta^{(3)}(x-y)
$$
At this time we can compute:
$$
\begin{align}
[Q,A^\sigma(y)]
&= [\int d^3x. \mathcal{P}^\nu \partial_\nu\theta(x), A^\sigma(y)]\\
&= \int d^3x. [\mathcal{P}(x), A^\sigma(y)] \partial_\nu\theta(x)\\
&= \int d^3x. (\delta^{\nu\sigma} - \frac{\partial^\nu \partial^\sigma}{\partial^2})\delta^{(3)}(x-y) \partial_\nu\theta(x)\\
&= \partial^\sigma\theta(x) - \partial^\sigma\theta(x)\\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$
which does not contradick to $Q = 0$ as what we previously computed.

So the reason why we don't talk about the Noether charge for local gauge symmetry is that it is always 0 and does not equal to quantum generator $[Q_\theta, A_\mu(x)] = -\partial_\mu \theta(x)$.

In fact, we can prove that the Noether charge for any local symmetry is always 0!! (See the answer by Peter Kravchuk: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66251. Note that the accepted answer there is incorrect...).

Consider the transformation:
$$
\phi(x) \mapsto \phi(x) + \epsilon(x)\mathcal{F}(x)
$$
under which we require the action is invariant when $\epsilon(x)=\epsilon$ is a constant. Then we have
$$
\delta S = \int d^4x. \partial_\mu \epsilon(x) J^\mu(x)
$$
It should be accentrated that the Euler-Lagrange equation is derived by requiring the stability under variation that is compactly supported!! So if $\mathcal{F}(x)$ is not, we should let $\epsilon(x)\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^4)$. This is the case that we usually use. But if instead the transformation is local, i.e. $\mathcal{F}(x)\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^4)$, as is the case for local gauge transformation, we can set
$$
\epsilon(x) = \Theta(x^0) := \frac{1+sign(x^0)}{2}
$$
the Heaviside function. In this situation we get on-shell:
$$
0 = \delta S = \int d^4x. \partial_\mu \Theta(x^0) J^\mu(x) = 
\int d^4x. \delta(x^0) J^0(x) = \int d^3x. J^0(x) = Q
$$