# Where does this term "shell" with prefix "on-/off-" come from?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, soft-question, terminology, history

Is there some historical reasons or is there a specific reason behind it?

This question is connected to:
[Why on-shell vs. off-shell matters?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59333/why-on-shell-vs-off-shell-matters)

Comment: In your linked Physics.SE question, there's a link to [this WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell). Are you looking for something more in-depth?

Comment: Essentially already answered at the [linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59333/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A particle is said to be on-shell if it satisfies the relativistic dispersion relation,

$$E^2 = p^2 +m^2$$

in units wherein $c=\hbar=1$. If you graph it, you obtain a hyperboloid surface (in 4-momentum space) for massive particles, and a cone for massless particles, like a photon. This is known as the **mass shell**, it is quite literally a shell or surface. The momentum of a real particle can be represented as a vector **on the surface**, hence the expression **on shell.** Virtual particles do not have these on the surface, hence they are **off shell.**

[image]

---

[image]

**Source:** Perimeter Institute, *A Deeper Dive: On Shell and Off Shell*

Comment: Of course, the term "on-shell" has broadened significantly to refer field or particle trajectories that obey the EoMs.

Answer (score 6):

The term "shell" originally derives from the non-relativistic version of the answer by @JamalS. In a non-relativistic theory, a free particle satisfies the following dispersion relation
$$
E = \frac{ {\bf p}^2 }{ 2m } 
$$
For a fixed energy a particle satisfies
$$
{\bf p}_x^2 + {\bf p}_y^2 + {\bf p}_z^2 = 2 m E 
$$
In momentum space, this is precisely the equation of a spherical "shell" with radius $\sqrt{2mE}$. (See a plot [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20x%5E2%20%2b%20y%5E2%20%2b%20z%5E2%20=%201))

Now, in momentum space, the 3-momentum of a particle is described by a point. If $E$ is fixed, then the 3-momentum of the particle is only allowed to lie on the spherical shell described above, and is therefore said to be on-shell.

In quantum mechanics, a particle is allowed to *not* satisfy the dispersion relation. Thus, the momentum of a particle in quantum mechanics is allowed to *not* lie on the shell, and can be off-shell.

In a relativistic theory, the dispersion relation changes to
$$
E^2 = {\bf p}^2 + m^2 \implies {\bf p}_x^2 +  {\bf p}_y^2 + {\bf p}_z^2 = E^2 - m^2 
$$
The corresponding constant $E$ surface is again a spherical shell, (this time of radius $\sqrt{ E^2 - m^2 }$)