# Which transformations *aren't* symmetries of a Lagrangian?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

As far as I understand, Noether's theorem for fields works, as explained in [David Tong's QFT lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/one.pdf) (page 14) for example, by saying that a transformation $\phi(x) \mapsto \phi(x) + \delta \phi (x)$ is called a symmetry if it produces a change in the Lagrangian density which can be expressed as a four divergence, $$\delta \mathcal{L} = \partial_{\mu} F^{\mu}\tag{1.35} $$ for some 4-vector field $F^{\mu}$.

We thengo onto show that the change in this Lagrangian density may also be expressed *for an arbitrary transformation* as

$$\delta \mathcal{L} = \partial_{\mu}\bigg(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_{\mu} \phi)}\delta \phi\bigg)\tag{1.37}.$$

Which *is* a 4-divergence. So how could we say any transformation *is not* a symmetry in the sense above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The point is that eq. (1.35) should hold *off-shell* to have a symmetry, while eq. (1.37) may only hold *on-shell.*

[The term *on-shell* (in this context) means that the Euler-Lagrange equations are satisfied. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59333/2451) Phys.SE post.]

In other words: On-shell, the action will only change with at most a boundary term for *any* infinitesimal variation, whether or not it is a symmetry.

Phrased differently: By a *symmetry* is meant an *off-shell symmetry.* An *on-shell symmetry* is a vacuous notion.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course! And eq. (1.35) should be off-shell so that  the action is still a minimum (as the nearby trajectories of the new trajectory will have their action changed by the same amount each)

Comment: On another note, even if $\delta \mathcal{L}$ doesn't have an off-shell 4-divergence form, can it , for example, happen to still equal zero in the on-shell trajectory and thus give a conserved 4-current density, even though our transformation wasn't a symmetry?