# On-shell and off-shell transformations in Noether's theorem

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, symmetry, action, noethers-theorem

For any transformation of the fields, 
$$\varphi\to\varphi'=\varphi+\delta\varphi$$
the change in the Lagrangian can be written as 
$$\delta\mathcal L = \text{EoM} + \partial_\mu j^\mu\tag{1}$$where "EoM" represents the equations of motion (Euler-Lagrange equations) and all other terms can be written as a total derivative of some function $j^\mu$, which is a known function in terms of the Lagrangian.

I would like to distinguish the different realizations of transformations. Let's assume that the transformation (1) leaves the action invariant, $\delta S=0$.

1. $\delta\mathcal L=0$

   - EoM $=0$, "on-shell": Noether current is conserved, $\partial_\mu j^\mu=0$.
   - EoM $=\partial_\mu b^\mu\neq0$, "off-shell": modified Noether current $J^\mu = j^\mu+b^\mu$ is conserved, $\partial_\mu J^\mu=0$.
2. $\delta\mathcal L =\partial_\mu a^\mu \neq 0$, "quasi-symmetry"

   - EoM $=0$, "on-shell": modified Noether current $J^\mu = j^\mu-a^\mu$ is conserved, $\partial_\mu J^\mu=0$.
   - EoM $=\partial_\mu b^\mu\neq0$, "off-shell": modified Noether current $J^\mu = j^\mu-a^\mu+b^\mu$ is conserved, $\partial_\mu J^\mu=0$.

Is this listing correct?

> What roles do the terms "on/off-shell" and "(quasi) symmetry" play in Noether's theorem?

Related: [one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144389/), [two](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51327/), [three](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11313/), [four](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328473/), [five](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165286/).

Comment: See also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56851/noethers-current-expression-in-peskin-and-schroeder/56905#56905) for getting oriented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The assumption in [Noether's (first) theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) is an off-shell$^1$ quasisymmetry of the action $S$. It leads to an off-shell Noether identity
   off-shell Noether identity 
   $$d_{\mu} J^{\mu} ~\equiv~ - \frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi^{\alpha}} \tag{A}Y_0^{\alpha}.$$ 
   Here $J^{\mu}$ is the full Noether current, which is necessarily non-trivial; and $Y_0^{\alpha}$ is a (vertical) symmetry generator. The off-shell identity (A) in turn implies an on-shell continuum equation/conservation law.
2. An on-shell quasisymmetry of the action $S$ is a tautology. It has not an associated continuum equation/conservation law. Even a strict symmetry of the action $S$ (or the Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$) on-shell has not an associated continuum equation/conservation law.$^2$
3. OP is only considering so-called vertical transformations $\delta\phi$, i.e. $\delta x^{\mu}=0$, which carries certain simplifications in the form of the Noether current.

--

$^1$The words *on-shell* and *off-shell* refer to whether the Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations (=EOM) are satisfied or not.

$^2$ Here is another heuristic argument: Ignoring various technical assumptions & details, there is morally speaking a bijective correspondence between off-shell quasisymmetries and on-shell conservation laws, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24596/2451) Phys.SE post. In particular, all on-shell conservation laws are already explained by off-shell quasisymmetries alone. In other words, there is no room for on-shell quasisymmetries to play an independent role in this correspondence.

Comment: If the conservation law is considered on-shell, why start with an off-shell transformation? -- If for a general transformation, $\delta\mathcal L=\text{EoM}+\partial_\mu j^\mu$ and now for a particular vertical transformation, $\delta\mathcal L=\partial_\mu\Lambda^\mu$, we subtract both to get $\text{EoM}+\partial_\mu(j^\mu-\Lambda^\mu)=0$. If we assume on-shell, this becomes $\partial_\mu(j^\mu-\Lambda^\mu)=0$ and we have our conservation law.

Comment: I understand that for an "on-shell" quasi symmetry, $\Lambda$ in my previous comment should become $j$, therefore the conservation law is a trivial equation. However, using this logic leads to the conclusion that also afterwards in my last step, $\Lambda\to j$ and the equation becomes trivial. What am I missing?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I think this together with another answer (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/438369/127780) and this paper ([arXiv:1510.07038](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07038)) has solved my confusion.