# How does satisfying the Euler-Lagrange equation put a Classical Path on-shell?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, action

I am thinking of what the Euler-Lagrange equation,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0
$$
 specifically represents in satisfying the conditions to put a particle "on-shell" in terms of the Classical Action (1).

I know that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = p$ I also know that putting a particle "on-shell" is equivalent to stating, in natural units, $E^2 = p^2 + m^2$ (2). In this context, what physical quantities do, the following represent?
$$
\tag{1}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}
$$
$$
\tag{2}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right)
$$
and
$$
\tag{3}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}
$$

## References

1. [The Euler–Lagrange Equations and Noether’s Theorem, Springer, (top of page 26)](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjphYrq3I3KAhUCGA8KHYQkAqMQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783642156236-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1021541-p174033656&usg=AFQjCNHsL-9C_11fcJQWaTkDucXlx2WMvg&sig2=Ska1VcHa6akpMEV8NiN2ng&bvm=bv.110151844,d.ZWU)
2. [On-Shell and Off-Shell, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell)

Comment: It seems that the question (v3) is spurred by different uses of the word _on-shell,_ see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90866/2451).

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry I grabbed a coffee and edited it to make more sense of my thoughts! :) V4 is the final version as I really want to know the dimensions of the E-L equation