# Relation between old and new Hamiltonian for Canonical Transformations

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, phase-space

The question I am asking was asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/614329/) but was never given a satisfactory answer and so I will rephrase it and add more detail.

In chapter 9 of Goldstein,when talking about a canonical transformatio $(p,q,t) \to (P,Q,t)$ where Hamilton's principle is obeyed:

[image]

He mentions that (9.8) is a sufficient but not necessary condition.

However in chapter 10 between eqs. (10.1) and (10.2) he states that

[image]

which we derived using (9.8) with $\lambda=1$. How has the sufficient condition become a necessary one?

I though the idea of (9.8) is that if the integrands are both equal it is one way to satisfy (9.6) and (9.7) but not the only way?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Ref. 1. later simply declares in the text under eq. (9.11) that an *canonical transformation* (CT) by definition satisfies eq. (9.8) with $\lambda=1$.

For the various definitions of a canonical transformation (CT), see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105613/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Chapter 9. See text under eq. (9.11).