What exactly in QFT makes a field/particle on- or off-shell?

If we are to write down a quantum field definition, could we tell if the definition is on- or off-shell?

If we are to write down a quantum field interaction, could we tell from the expression and not the Feynman diagram that the field is on- or off-shell?

In general, how do we write down on- or off-shell fields and processes in QFT?


I heard that the Dirac delta function is used to pick out the on-shell particles from the off-shell ones?

Edit: I would like some intuition as indicated by the tag to this question. Specifically if we could just look at an expression and determine if it is on shell or off shell. @paulina provided a nice example of this in the comments, and more like it would be appreciated.

off shell fields only appear in intermediate steps of the interaction. you can tell that they are off shell since instead of having definite momenta, their momenta are integrated over. i think you can figure out how the delta function plays into this yourself.

@paulina so I assume that the delta function is used to pick out the definite (a particular) momenta from the integrated momenta by including it in the same expression?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59333/2451 and links therein.

On-shell vs off-shell means solving vs not solving equations of motion. For particles it means obeying vs not obeying $p^2 = -m^2$.

@paulina if you could provide your answer for that example and any others like it, that would be great. Thank you


What exactly in QFT makes a field/particle on- or off-shell?

Restating what is on this link and what the commenters have said: "on-shell" means it obeys the classical equations of motions; "off-shell" means it doesn't.
Recall that one can consider classical fields, and those classical fields have equations of motion generated from a Lagrange density. For example, if the Lagrange density is
$$
\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial\phi) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\dot\phi^2 - \nabla \phi^2 -m^2 \phi\right)\;,\tag{1}
$$
then the classical equation of motion for the field is
$$
\ddot \phi - \nabla^2\phi + m^2\phi =0\;.\tag{2}
$$
For the Lagrange density of Eq. (1), fields that obey Eq. (2) are "on-shell." Fields that don't are "off-shell."
Recall too that we can get to a quantum theory via the path-integral approach. All field configurations contribute to the path integral, but weighted by the exponential of the classical action:
$$
I = \int \mathcal{D}\phi e^{i/\hbar\int d^4 x \mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial \phi)}\;.
$$
So, we care about both on-shell and off-shell fields in QFT, but the classical field configurations that obey the classical equations of motion are important because they make the action stationary.


If we are to write down a quantum field definition, could we tell if the definition is on- or off-shell?


You can tell by checking if it obeys the classical equation of motion or not.


If we are to write down a quantum field interaction, could we tell from the expression and not the Feynman diagram that the field is on- or off-shell?


No.


In general, how do we write down on- or off-shell fields and processes in QFT?


I don't know that we would usually do something like that. But if you write down a field that doesn't obey the classical equation of motion, it has some off-shell component.

I heard that the Dirac delta function is used to pick out the on-shell particles from the off-shell ones?

Despite ending with a question mark, this sentence does not seem to be a question.


Update Re Comment:

"I wanted some intuition, specifically, if we could just look at an expression in QFT and determine if it is on shell of off shell."

No, not generally. You can't just "look at" any "expression" and know.
As for the intuition, take a step back. Do not trouble yourself with quantum mechanics or field theory. Just think back to good ol' classical mechanics.
Consider the classical mechanical Lagrangian of a simple harmonic oscillator:
$$
L(x, v) = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 - \frac{1}{2}k x^2\;.\tag{3}
$$
It does not make sense to ask if this "expression" is "on-shell" or "off-shell." It is just a function of two independent variables $x$ and $v$. (Yes, $x$ and $v$ are independent variables. I have not yet made any connection between any trajectory $x(t)$ and the variable $x$ appearing in Eq. (3). Similarly, I have not yet made any connection between the time derivative of a trajectory $\dot x(t)$ and the variable $v$ appearing in Eq. (3).)
If I want to figure out which trajectories obey the classical equations of motion, that is, which trajectories are "on-shell," I proceed by considering an arbitrary trajectory $x(t)$ and evaluating the action:
$$
S[x] = \int dt L(x(t), \dot x(t))\;.
$$
It is a strange and wonderful fact of nature that the classical trajectories minimize the action. By applying the calculus of variation, we can figure out an equation that the on-shell trajectories must follow. Namely:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial v}\right|_{x=x(t), v=\dot x(t)} - \left.\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\right|_{x=x(t), v=\dot x(t)} = 0\;.\tag{4}
$$
For the example Lagrangian of Eq. (3) our Eq. (4) says:
$$
m\ddot x(t) + k x(t) = 0\;. \tag{5}
$$
The on-shell trajectories for a SHO are the trajectories that obey the above equation of motion. (Which are the actual trajectories that physical masses on springs actually take (well, approximately).)
Ok, now suppose I want to Fourier transform Eq. (5). I can do so, and I end up with the following:
$$
-m\omega^2 \tilde x(\omega) + k x(\omega) = 0\;, \tag{6}
$$
Which, again describes on-shell solutions as solutions to an equation (but no longer a differential equation). The on-shell solutions in Fourier space are now seen to obey:
$$
\omega=\pm\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\;.
$$
Any on-shell or off-shell trajectory x(t) can be written as:
$$
x(t) = \int d\omega e^{-i\omega t}\tilde x(\omega)\;.
$$
But, if you want something on-shell you must force the solution to obey the equation of motion, which you could do by inserting a couple delta functions like:
$$
x_{cl}(t) = \int d\omega e^{-i\omega t}\tilde x(\omega)\left(\delta(\omega - \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}) + \delta(\omega + \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}})\right)
$$
$$
= \tilde x(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}) e^{-i\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t} + \tilde x(-\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}) e^{+i\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t}
$$
$$
= A\sin(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t) + B\cos(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}} t)
$$

Thank you for your answer. Well, that link was added by an editor and not by me. The the first comment by @paulina under my question gave something that I was looking for and provides some good distinction between the 2. Perhaps I was not clear about it, and I can improve on it next time, but I wanted some intuition, specifically, if we could just look at an expression in QFT and determine if it is on shell of off shell. Written communication is difficult sometimes
