# Charge not conserved in scalar QED?

Tags: conservation-laws, gauge-theory, field-theory, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

Since conservation of charge seems to be a well known concept, I am hoping that I am missing something and that the conclusion is incorrect.  However, I have been unable to disprove this.  Let me outline the situation as follows.

**Overview**

Consider the following Lagrangian for scalar QED and field $\varphi$:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}=\overline{D_\mu\varphi}D^\mu\varphi-U(|\varphi|^2)-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu},\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $$D_\mu=\partial_\mu-iA_\mu\varphi.\tag{2}$$

One set of Euler-Lagrange equations is:
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta A_\mu}=i(\overline\varphi\partial_\mu\varphi-\varphi\partial_\mu\overline\varphi)+2A^\mu|\varphi|^2+\partial_\nu F^{\mu\nu}=0.\tag{3}
\end{align}

If we consider the global gauge symmetry transformation $\varphi\to\varphi+i\epsilon\varphi$, then Noether's first theorem gives the following conservation law (for charge, see e.g. [[1]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57901/)) on solutions of $\delta\mathcal{S}=0$:
\begin{align}
\partial_\mu j^\mu:=\partial_\mu\left[i(\overline\varphi\partial_\mu\varphi-\varphi\partial_\mu\overline\varphi)+2A^\mu|\varphi|^2\right]=0.\tag{4}
\end{align}

**Question:** does the integral of the charge density $j^0$ vanish identically?  If so, does this mean that nothing is conserved?

**My attempt at an answer:** Yes.  To see this, we integrate the continuity equation over $\mathbb{R}^3$ and apply Gauss's Theorem:
\begin{align}
\partial_0Q:=\partial_0\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}j^0 d^3 x=-\sum_{\mu=1}^3\int_{R^2} j^\mu \bigr\rvert_{|x_\mu|\to\infty}d^2x.\tag{5}
\end{align}
Here, we say that $Q=\int j^0$ is the total charge.

We assume that the fields $\varphi$ and $F$ vanish as $\max_{\mu\ge 1}(x_\mu)\to\infty$.  This is a natural boundary condition for physical observables.  Then the fluxes $j^\mu$ clearly vanish in this limit.  Thus, our conservation law becomes:
\begin{align}
\partial_0\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}j^0 d^3 x=0.\tag{6}
\end{align}
But 
$$j^0=\delta\mathcal{L}/\delta A_0-\partial_\nu F^{0\nu}=-\partial_\nu F^{0\nu}\tag{7}$$ 
on solutions, so we can equivalently rewrite the charge integral using Gauss's Theorem as follows:
\begin{align}
Q=-\sum_{\nu\ge 1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}F^{0\nu}\bigr|_{|x_\nu|\to\infty} d^3 x.\tag{8}
\end{align}
Since the fields vanish at infinity, we obtain:
\begin{align}
Q\equiv 0.\tag{9}
\end{align}

In other words, if correct, then this shows that the charge for this system is identically zero, and that nothing is conserved (it seems incorrect to call $d0/dt\equiv 0$ a conservation law rather than a tautology/identity).

**Related Links**

There are a few other questions users asked that have some relation to this.  However, I do not believe the actual charge integral's conservation was anywhere addressed.  [One](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26990/) shows that the charge density can be rewritten as a total divergence, from which the argument follows, of course.  [This article](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57901/) includes the fact that there is no conservation law for the local gauge symmetry, but does not clarify this for the global symmetry case (which should be a special case of the local results).  [Another](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48305/) gives an overview of charge conservation.

Edit:

[Another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206180/charge-not-conserved-in-scalar-qed) also discusses charge conservation, but it seems to be more concerned with the interpretation of the charge density.  I am instead asking if the density is conserved at all.

Comment: The fields do vanish at infinity, but the measure of $d^3x$ blows up in the same limit. So you have to be more careful. In fact, you can check that $j^0 \sim 1/r^2$ at large $r$ (i.e. near infinity) but $d^3 x \sim r^2 \sin\theta d\theta d\phi$. The power of $r^2$ cancel  and give a finite result.

Comment: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic624321.files/09-scalarQED.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your conclusions have nothing to do with scalar QED or quantum mechanics for that matter. Let's start from your $j^0 = -\partial_\mu F^{0 \mu}$, then you erroneously applied gauss law to find $Q$ vanishes at infinity. The reason is that in your surface integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}dS$ need not vanish, because the field need only vanish as $1/r$ for the integral to be finite.

This is just classical electrodynamics, where $E^i= F^{0i}$ so that $\rho = j^0 = -\partial_\mu F^{0\mu} = -\nabla\cdot E$ is just Guass law and 
\begin{align}
Q = \int_{\text{surface}} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A} \rightarrow \text{finite if }E\xrightarrow{r\rightarrow\infty}1/r
\end{align}