# Introduction to Gauge Symmetries: Good, Bad or Ugly?

Tags: gauge-theory, definition, noethers-theorem, gauge-symmetry

I'm trying to come up with a good (as in intuitive and not 'too wrong') definition of a gauge symmetry.

This is what I have right now:

> A dynamical symmetry is a (differentiable) group of transformations that
>   respects system dynamics, ie maps solutions to solutions.
>
> A rigid symmetry is a dynamical symmetry that maps solutions to
>   *different* solutions. A rigid symmetry has a Noether charge that is only conserved *on-shell*, ie dependent on the equations of motion.
>
> A gauge symmetry is a dynamical symmetry that maps solutions to
>   *identical* solutions up to 'parametrization' or 'gauge'; in particular, the solutions correspond to the same initial conditions and physics and only differ in
>   their mathematical description. A gauge symmetry has a Noether charge
>   that is conserved *off-shell*, ie independent of the equations of
>   motion.
>
> As an example, we take classical mechanics: In general, time
>   dependence of the solutions matter as reparametrization changes
>   velocities. However, in the relativistic case 4-velocities are
>   constrained to 'length' $c$ and dynamics need to be independent of the
>   particular choice of the 'unphysical' 3-velocities.

First of all, is this correct? If so, is there a better choice of wording? Should anything be added?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13870/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the second Noether theorem doesn't tell us that the Noether current associated to a local (i.e. gauge) symmetry is conserved off shell, but that it rather *vanishes on shell*. See the paper of M. Forger and H. Römer, "Currents and the energy-momentum tensor in classical field theory: a fresh look at an old problem", Ann. Phys. 309 (2004) 306-389, arXiv:hep-th/0307199 for a thorough discussion on this matter. Nonetheless, it has an equivalent formulation in terms of an off-shell conservation law (then called a "Noether identity") through the map taking infinitesimal local gauge parameters to infinitesimal field variations, but the conserved current in this case is *not* the canonical Noether current associated to the symmetry. It is only so if the equations os motion hold, in which case it vanishes. In some cases, however, this off-shell conservation law is indeed a *covariant* conservation law (i.e. with respect to some connection field which is natural to the theory) for an "improved" partial canonical Noether current corresponding to a "pure gauge" sector of the model. This is the case, for instance, of Yang-Mills theories minimally coupled to matter. The corresponding "covariant" conservation law in the matter sector then only holds on shell. Such a structure, however, may not be present in all models which admit local symmetries.