# Gauge Theory of Superconductors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, higgs, gauge-invariance

I'm trying to understand better the nature of the gauge redundancy and the Higgs mechanism in superconductors.

Specifically, I'm looking for a good reference that explains monopoles, vortices, and how to think about the different phases of the Abelian Higgs model in terms of confinement and condensation of these defects.

I suppose more generally I'd like to understand gauge theories and how different phases relate to confinement and condensation.

Related to: [Phase diagram of gauge + matter theories](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/206784/).

Comment: The basics are in a book by Rubakov (Classical theory of gauge fields) and a paper by Greiter http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503400. Perhaps you may find http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404327 useful, too. Otherwise results are scattered all around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beautiful (in my opinion) source in which higgs mechanism nature of superconducting phenomena is discussed, is Steven Weinberg's QFT Vol. 2, sec. 21.6. Topological nature of superconucting vortices is discussed in this section. Also, there is general discussion on topological configurations in QFT, with theoretical minimum, in Chapter 23.