# What is the importance of vector potential not being unique?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, vector-fields, gauge-invariance, magnetostatics

For a magnetic field we can have  different solutions of its vector potential.
What is the physical aspect of this fact? 
I mean, why the nature allows us not to have an unique vector potential of a field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "physical aspect of this fact". The physical variables are the electric and the magnetic field, not the potentials. Introducing the potential is *aesthetically and technically pleasing*, but it is not *necessary*. [A gauge symmetry is not a physical symmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13870/50583).

The reason you can have a non-unique potential is that every divergence-free field such as the magnetic field has a vector potential whose curl it is, but adding any gradient to that potential still gives the same magnetic field since the curl of a gradient is zero. The equation defining the magnetic vector potential is simply underdetermined.

Note that even the effect that is usually cited as showing the potentials being "physical", the [Aharanov-Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect), does not make the potential unique. The quantity that is relevant is the integral of the vector potential $A$ along a closed loop $\gamma$, and if we denote the region inside $\gamma$ as $U$, we have $\int_\gamma A = \int_U B$ by Stokes' theorem, so what really matters here is the *flux through the loop*, not the specific value of the potential. And one has to close the loop to observe a phase difference (or, well, [maybe not always](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0512179v2), but the phase is still only dependent on the flux, not on a gauge-variant potential value). In any case, this is a quantum effect. In the classical theory, the potential is definitely not "physical" in the sense of being measureable.