# In simple words, why does a Lorenz Gauge does not have any physical effects?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

I'm studying vector calculus via Arfken & Weber's "Mathematical Methods for Physicists", and, in page 40, he is deriving the electromagnetic wave equation.

During the demonstration he states that we can fix
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = 0$$
Where $\mathbf{A}$ is the vector magnetic potential, $\phi$ is the non-static electric potential, and $c$ is the speed of light.
He states that "this option for fixing the divergence of the vector potential, named [**Lorenz Gauge**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_gauge_condition), is to unlink the equations of both the potentials. It has no physical effect".

The last phrase is not clear to me. How does fixing the value of a vector field when studying electromagnetic equations will not have any implications, physically speaking?

As for my background, i've never been introduced formally to gauge theory. I know the basics of Group Theory and a little bit of representation theory, if that helps. (I've heard that classical electrodynamics has a $U(1)$ symmetry, does that have anything to do with this?)

Comment: Note that this is the Lorenz gauge (no t).

Comment: In simple words: Because of gauge symmetry.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13870/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247261/50583

Comment: @Qmechanic  could you explain? What is gauge symmetry?

Comment: Check this question, I think is what you are looking for [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/508036/lorenz-gauge-condition-in-helmholtz-equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/508036/lorenz-gauge-condition-in-helmholtz-equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the assertion of lack of physical effect refers specifically to the Lorenz gauge; rather it refers to the freedom to fix a gauge in in the first place. *Any* condition that can be fulfilled by a gauge transformation $A_\mu \mapsto A_\mu + \partial_\mu\,\psi$ for some $C^2$ scalar field $\psi$ is fair game: we solve our boundary problem for the 4-potential $A$ and then the physically measurable field is $F=\mathrm{d} A$. This latter $F$ is independent of the gauge because it is invariant under the gauge transformation.

The assertion is simply a statement of gauge symmetry, and that the fixing of the gauge cannot affect the measurable field $F$,

Comment: This answer is not exactly what i am looking for. As i previously said, i've never been introduced to gauge theory. All i know of group theory is what Lie groups are and some of its examples (SO, SU, etc) but i **don't** know how them relate to physics. Since the author mentioned this gauge before introducing groups in the book, i assumed that it could be a 'simple' explanation. When i say simple i mean that it can be phrased using vector calculus, basic group theory and, if necessary, introducing new concepts. I don't think this answer did this at all.

Comment: @VitorCGoergen Sorry, I thought the problem might be that the wording suggested this statement was something specific to the Lorentz gauge (the text's wording is a bit ambiguous). In that case, what it means is that the only physically measurable field is $F$. Therefore, any transformation we can make on $A$ that does not affect $F$ is not physically observable. So we are free to make such changes to $A$. This is gauge symmetry - it is the *redundancy* in Maxwells equations when they are formulated in terms of $A$ rather than $F$.

Comment: Thanks! That is a lot clearer now. So, when we came the transformation
$\mathbf{A} \rightarrow \mathbf{A} + \nabla \phi$, the $\nabla \phi$ is irrelevant to our "reality" because $\mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A} = \nabla \times (\mathbf{A} + \nabla \phi) = \nabla \times \mathbf{A} + \nabla \times \nabla \phi = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$. Is that correct? I've also verified that $\nabla \phi$ also unchanges Stokes Theorem. For me, it seems like the idea of $\nabla \phi$ is similar to that of a constant of integration in real analysis. 
Thanks. It was very helpful.