# Simplest example of a gauge theory?

Tags: gauge-theory

I am not a physicist. I’ve read some informal stuff about gauge theory and gauge symmetries, however it’s pretty abstract to me.

Can you give the simplest non-trivial example of a gauge theory? E.g. there exist Newtonian/classical gauge theories, then that would be helpful.

Note: I read in another question that “gauge theory” is used not to refer to a theory with a gauge symmetry, but one with a “gauge field” (not sure what that is).

Comment: This [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71476/gravity-as-a-gauge-theory?rq=1) might be helpful.

Comment: Did you look at classical electrodynamics?

Comment: I just found a great post by @tparker here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/267044/206691, followed by several other good answers. They answer the question, "What, in simplest terms, is gauge invariance?"

Answer (score 1):

One simple example is if the Lagrangian is a total derivative
$$ L(q,\dot{q},t) = \frac{dF(q,t)}{dt} .$$
This has a gauge symmetry $$\delta q(t)~=~\varepsilon(t),$$
where $q(t)$ plays the role of a gauge field and $\varepsilon(t)$ is a gauge parameter.

Comment: 3D abelian Chern-Simons theory $S[A] =\int \!A\wedge \mathrm{d}A$ is another simple example.

Comment: ...and any Lagrangian of the form $L(q_1,q_2)=f(\dot q_1-\dot q_2,q_1-q_2)$, with $\delta q_i(t)=\varepsilon(t)$.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Right.