# Is there a physical mechanism explaining the link between Gauge-Bosons and local Gauge-Invariance?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

Imposing local gauge-invariance naturally couples e.g. a charged fermion-field to the electromagnetic field.

To my understanding local gauge-invariance is imposed because a gauge in one system should not affect or fix the gauge outside its light cone. Is there a physical mechanism explaining why a gauge boson "generates" this property of local gauge invariance?

(I am curious if there is a physical interpretation of this connection between minimal coupling and local gauge invariance or is it just a mathematical coincidence?)

Comment: While it's not quite the same as your question,  you may find some of the answers here helpful, or at least thought-provoking: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/266992/123208

Comment: "Physical"? You don't mean fuzzy math in words? Gauge invariance, a highly formal and unintuitive structure,  was introduced by a mathematician (Weyl) and has tasteful geometrical underpinnings, but what would you rate as "physical"?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I do not know, if such an explanation exists! I just thought there might be an insight someone could share. To me "No there isn't" is an answer, too. I am just learning about this things, and as you say they are unintuitive. I kind of hoped that there might be some understandable connection between the local gauge invariance (which is kind of abstract) and a gauge Boson like the photon which is a more accessible thing (although very abstract too), in more physical terms. Maybe like some physicists explain the running coupling constant in terms of a polarized vacuum.

Comment: Which is a rather physical explanation/interpretation for an abstract result of a renormalisation-scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a physical mechanism explaining why a gauge boson "generates" this property of local gauge invariance?

I think you have it backwards.  Starting with the Lagrangian for fermions, if we require local transformation ($\psi \rightarrow \psi \prime = \psi e^{iq\phi(x^\mu)}$) invariance, then we have to change the derivative in the Lagrangian into a "covariant" derivative, which includes a field term $A_\mu$ with its own transformation property that's related to the original local transformation ($A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu ' = A_\mu - \partial_\mu \phi(x^\mu))$. This field is the photon, which is generated **in response to** the local transformation invariance requirement.  Notice I haven't said anything about "gauge" yet.

The photon field happens to *have* a gauge invariance, because we can add the 4-gradient of any scalar function to $A_\mu$ and there will be no change to the measurable E and M fields.

The reason I think the local transformations are usually called "local gauge invariance" is that if a  physical system is invariant with respect to a global transformation, and it remains invariant when that transformation is considered locally, then it is said to have a gauge invariance.

> I kind of hoped that there might be some understandable connection between the local gauge invariance (which is kind of abstract) and a gauge Boson like the photon which is a more accessible thing (although very abstract too), in more physical terms.

Unfortunately, AFAIK the photon field appears because the math says it must, there is no "physical" reason.

*(Those of you critiquing this response, please be gentle, it's my first attempt at answering a question on physics.stackexchange, I'm hoping it's acceptable!)*